# Macros not working from network location even after added to Trusted location

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have some users that use macros on their excel documents that are saved on one of our internal file servers. I have added the network location to the trusted locations however when the user opens the file it says "Microsoft has blocked macros from running because the source of this file is untrusted". I have tried adding the parent folder and selecting the apply to subfolders check box and the exact folder location but no matter what it will not allow the user to run the macros properly.

Note: This was working for the user prior to getting a new windows 11 PC but the version of office 365 was the same from computer to computer. Another user is able to do this with no issues and the settings are identical from computer to computer as far as I am able to see.

We are using a home version of Office 365 because this is a small office and the family plan made more financial sense the going the business route.

New HP computer with plenty of resources running windows 11.

Please help any suggestions are welcome I am at a wall with my google searches and prior knowledge of office.

Macro Settings:

[image]

File Settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Scott if you could please add the Photo showing that the file locations are in the trusted locations tab as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: Besides adding the network share location inside the Office "Trusted Locations", you also need to add the location to the Local intranet zone in *Control Panel > Internet Options > Security > Local intranet > Sites*. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Please refer to '[Macros from the internet will be blocked by default in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/security/internet-macros-blocked)'

Comment: @harrymc I have tried adding this and it did not resolve the issue either. I aslo tried Trusted sites instead of local intranet to see if it would make a difference and lowered the security to low. None of these changes removed the marco block message

Answer (score 2):

I found that even setting the trusted locations inside Excal options in the Trust Center did not work in regards to network access and I believe that Microsoft is upping their security.

This is what worked for me.

On a Windows device goto `Control Panel > Internet Options >  Securrity Tab > Trusted Sites > Sites`  and add your network IP in this format, `file://192.168.1.1`.
Also remember to uncheck the `Require Server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone`.
See below image,
[Trusted Zone Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/images/security/trusted-sites-dialog-example.png)

Cheers

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Tymric, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same behavior - using MS Subscription Product - Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise on a company-owned machine.

Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2303 Build 16.0.16227.20202) 32-bit

It seems that something is scanning my documents (which are rather long) even though the file is saved in a local trusted location.

Behavior is also occurring with my personal device with Antivirus turned off.

My issues are with Word Documents but it appears to be the same issue as reported with Excel files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).